# Android versions in my android application

Tags: android

I have created an android application and in that application I created folder 'values' and 'values-v14' in res folder.

What will happen if my application installing in version of 15, from where  will it take the values: from values or values-v14?

Answer (score 1):

See [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

Description for Platform Version (API level) qualifier on the same page:

> The API level supported by the device. For example, v1 for API level 1
>   (devices with Android 1.0 or higher) and v4 for API level 4 (devices
>   with Android 1.6 or higher). See the Android API levels document for
>   more information about these values.
>
> Caution: Android 1.5 and 1.6 only match resources with this qualifier
>   when it exactly matches the platform version. See the section below
>   about Known Issues for more information.

So `v14` resources will be chosen for API level 14 devices and higher otherwise `values` folder will be used.